# Insert into third table where 2 tables have same Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a huge database and want to process it by smaller chunks so I'm trying to write scripts and copy rows onto a temporary table, process it and then copy them back.

Now I've copied around 1000 rows into `PersonMeta` from old database and now  want to insert corresponding rows for `People` table.

So basically I want to insert data from `olddb.People` into `newdb.People` where `newdb.PersonMeta` and `newdb.People` have the same code.

I've created this script but for some reason it doesn't copy all the rows. For example it copies 960 rows when it should copy 1000.

```
INSERT INTO [newdb].[dbo].[People] ([Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[PersonId])
SELECT fp.[Id]
      ,fp.[Name]
      ,fp.[PersonId]
FROM [olddb].[dbo].[People] fp
INNER JOIN [newdb].[dbo].[PersonMeta] pm on
pm.PersonId = fp.PersonId
```

#### edit:

I originally wrote 100 rows where it was 1000 rows. So the query is selecting 960 (40 less)

#### edit 2

The `People` table has some duplicate values for `PersonId` column. I removed them and now after I run the query it copies 956 rows (4 less then before).

#### edit 3:

I created [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5f71b103ab715facd75416e0ce4cfda2) and it seems to be working just fine.

However, I did some queries on the database. Turns out when I query with a `RIGHT JOIN` the value for those records which are not copied are all NULL. So when I run the following query:

```
Select fp.*, fp.personid, pm.personid
From [olddb].[dbo].[People] fp
right join [newdb].[dbo].[PersonMeta] pm on
fp.personid = pm.personid
```

It returns this:

[image]

Is there another approach I could try to copy the data?

Comment: Your query looks fine, can you provide a sample data and desired results as formatted text please.

Comment: seems the id is not auto increment

Comment: is seems you duplicate PersonId kye in newdb.People or PersonMeta tables which creates those records

Comment: @sami The database has millions of records. Not sure how to create sample to create the same result. It's going to be very hard to do so

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin No I checked the results. There are a few rows in the old table that are not present in the new table. No duplicates.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori creae a fiddle and share details https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b446f2d177c437b7eae413ab56dbf750

Comment: ` I want to insert data from olddb.People into newdb.People where newdb.PersonMeta and newdb.People have the same code.` ...you want to insert into `newdb.People` and on the second part you are checking the code in `newdb.People`, it is bit confusing...please check

Comment: please share your table structure of all tables used in your query...

Comment: Please check select query result using PersonId column from both table. Check both table personid count using group by clause with having condition count(personid) > 1. So you will found duplicate personid in which table.

Comment: @JIKEN sorry for misleading. Please read the update on the question

Answer (score 0):

There may be a NULL value in the PersonID field on either table. If so, remove/update the NULL record and try again.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your record separately what is generating from your query.

Check the output of this query. It should create 100 rows as you are expecting.

```
SELECT fp.[Id]
      ,fp.[Name]
      ,fp.[PersonId]
FROM [olddb].[dbo].[People] fp
INNER JOIN [newdb].[dbo].[PersonMeta] pm on
pm.PersonId = fp.PersonId
```

But still if it creates more then your expected rows you may try some filters to test the result as `isnull(pm.PersonId,0)<>0 and isnull(fp.PersonId,0)<>0`.

So it filter out the record having `personId is null`, which may duplicate your record.
So final query for test was

```
SELECT fp.[Id]
      ,fp.[Name]
      ,fp.[PersonId]
FROM [olddb].[dbo].[People] fp
INNER JOIN [newdb].[dbo].[PersonMeta] pm on
pm.PersonId = fp.PersonId and isnull(pm.PersonId,0)<>0 and isnull(fp.PersonId,0)<>0
```

If still you can't figure out the issue then please share your table structure of tables which might help to understand the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my question I wrote 100 rows where it was 1000. So the query generated **less** rows than expected. I did what you said and checked the results. No `NULL` value for any of the rows. In fact I grouped them and all of the rows had the count of 1

Comment: so how many rows are returned from above query.....also what is the individual row count of your both tables used in query...

Comment: The `olddb.dbo.People` table has 6108798 records.` [newdb].[dbo].[PersonMeta] ` has 1000 records and the query results in 956 rows.

Answer (score 0):

OK Now I feel silly but the problem was that simply not all of the rows had a corresponding value in the old `People` table for `PersonMeta` table. I thought they had it because I used the `Id` in the query rather than `PersonId`.

In short the posted query was in fact correct.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to keep distinct and unique records in new table.

Below query will create same schema as of old table and copies all the data present in old table to new table.

select * into [newdb].[dbo].[People] from [olddb].[dbo].[People]

Now if you want to keep the data present in new table in sync with the unique records present in [newdb].[dbo].[PersonMeta]. you can simply do

delete from [newdb].[dbo].[People] where personid not in (select personid from [newdb].[dbo].[PersonMeta] )